# Unable to determine primary key field on custom table

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have a custom table that I'm basically modeling after the CustGroup table.

The table has two fields, one extends the `SysGroup` and the other is a `Name` type.  I added an index with `AllowDuplicates = No` and the one `SysGroup` field.

And on the table, I set the `PrimaryIndex` equal to my `SysGroup` field.

I delete the axapd.aoi file and restarted the AOS.  I also ran the cross reference update and `SysFlushAOD::main(null);`.

When I run the following code, the first line returns 0 and the second 1, meaning it was able to find a primary key.

```
info(strfmt("MyCustGroup: %1", new SysDictTable(40390).primaryKeyField())); // Returns 0
info(strfmt("CustGroup: %1", new SysDictTable(57).primaryKeyField())); // Returns 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does your index look like in the AOT? does it have a little '1' on the icon to indicate that it is primary?

Comment: Yes it does have a little 1.

Comment: Clutching straws here but instead of 40390, try: SysDictTable(tablenum(MyCustGroup)).primaryKeyField())); 
If you are copying the table across AOS services it may have a different TableID betweem them.

Comment: I just tried `info(strfmt("MyCustGroup: %1", new SysDictTable(tablenum(MyCustGroup)).primaryKeyField())); // Returns 0` and it doesn't work.  The main reason I wanted this was so that if the user right clicked on the PKey, they could rename it using standard AX functionality, but the rename button didn't appear.  So after some debugging, I found out that it as failing because it couldn't determine the PKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary key should extend you own extended data type (EDT) extending `SysGroup`.
In the relations node of the EDT have a normal relation to your table and key field. Then change your key field to extend from your EDT.

Set the `TableGroup` property of your table to `Group`.
Then make sure the table succeeds completely the [Best Practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548778%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) check.

If that does not solve your problem, export, delete and import your table.

Comment: AH! I forgot to add the normal relation on the EDT.